# conditions for different divs for drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have 2 droppable divs called *drop* and *drop1*, and 2 draggable elements called *drag1* and *drag2*. I want to make an alert when drag1 and drag2 is both inside drop and drop1. Meaning, both divs would have drag1 and drag2.

But because i did it in a separate function for each div, i cant seem to make the conditions appear together. How do i detect that both divs are occupied with both drag1 and drag2 and alert only when it happens?

Javascript:

```
$(".drop").droppable({
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        if ($("#drag1, #drag1", $(".drop")).length === 2) {
                          alert("correct");
                        }
});

$(".drop1").droppable({
                    drop: function (event, ui) {
                        if ($("#drag1, #drag2", $(".drop1")).length === 2) {
                          alert("correct");
                         }
});
```

Html:

```
<img id="drag1" draggable="true" src="images/equation1_3.png">
<img  id="drag2" draggable="true" src="images/equation1_2.png">

<div class="drop" id="div1"></div>
<div class="drop1" id="div2"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".drop1, .drop").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
    if ($("#drag1, #drag2", $(".drop1")).length === 2 && $("#drag1, #drag2", $(".drop")).length === 2) {
      alert("correct");
    }
});
```

Have you tried initializing events on both divs together?